# Excel - Best file format for macro and forms

Tags: excel, vba

I make a lot of workbooks where there is no data in the workbooks themselves, but there are macros and forms attached. I generally format these in .xlsb or occasionally .xlsm file format, but I'm wondering if there is a format where there is no actual workbook attached. Just like a file you can open in Excel that will launch the macro?

It just seems pretty inefficient to include a blank workbook that I just autohide on load.

Comment: Have you looked at saving as an xlam (Add-in)?  Typically that's what you'd use if you don't need to see the workbook (though it's still there, just hidden)

Comment: Ooh, no I hadn't. I always thought that was more of a "tools in the ribbon" sort of thing. But I'll give it a try. I imagine it'd be able to programmatically close itself?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the version of Excel, when you load up Excel it automatically opens a Personal workbook which isn't visible.

Normally this is created when you record a macro and close all windows. It will then ask you to save it to the file. I would then set up shortcuts for the Macros.